# Sorting Table based on column Name from seperate table

Tags: sql-server

I have two separate tables, one transaction table and one table with list of reports to be generated.
The table with reports has conditions to be met and sorting orders.

```
Transaction

Emp_ID  Amount  Date

1       100     2020-01-01
2       90      2020-01-04
3       85      2020-01-02
4       40      2020-01-07
5       60      2020-01-08
```

```
ReportMaster

ReportID    Sorting     Asc_Desc
1           Amount      Desc
2           Date        Asc
3           Amount      Asc
```

The final report will be showing top 2 results of each report in a union.

```
ReportID    Emp_ID  Amount  Date        Row_Number
1           1       100     2020-01-01  1
1           2       90      2020-01-04  2
2           1       100     2020-01-01  1
2           3       85      2020-01-02  2
3           4       40      2020-01-07  1
3           5       60      2020-01-08  2
```

Ive hit a dead end with the logic for this. used an order clause with the "sorting" value it would only return Amount/Department instead of values in the corresponding column. Bear in mind the actual data set contains 20ish columns and 50-60 reports, so writing case statements to order is kind of tedious.

Are recursive statements required? Or is there an alternate method to achieve this?

Comment: This feels like something for the presentation layer, or an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Having a dynamic sort expression requires dynamic SQL, and that's not really an ideal solution for this.

Comment: If this is the route that someone has decided to go down, then I presume they intend you to generate dynamic SQL.  If a language (e.g. .net) is in use, maybe they mean you to build inline SQL, using these factors.

Answer (score 0):

Try the sql below :

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ReportTypes') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ReportTypes
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Results
CREATE TABLE #Results (
ReportID INT,
Emp_ID INT,
Amount DECIMAL(18, 2),
Date DATETIME,
RowNumber INT
)

SELECT ReportId, Sorting, Asc_Desc
INTO #ReportTypes
FROM ReportMaster

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #ReportTypes) > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ReportId INT, @Sorting VARCHAR(50), @Asc_Desc VARCHAR(50)
    SELECT TOP 1 @ReportID = ReportId, @Sorting = Sorting, @Asc_Desc = Asc_Desc FROM #ReportTypes

    SET @sql = @sql + ' INSERT INTO #Results ' 
            + ' SELECT ' + CAST(@ReportId AS VARCHAR) + ' ,Emp_ID, Amount, Date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ' + @Sorting + ' ' + @Asc_Desc + ') AS RowNumber FROM [Transactions];'

    DELETE FROM #ReportTypes WHERE ReportId = @ReportId 
END

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

SELECT ReportID, Emp_ID, Amount, Date, RowNumber AS [Row_Number]
FROM #Results
WHERE RowNumber <= 2
ORDER BY ReportID, RowNumber
```